# Update Not null in all table columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I want to update null to not null columns with one query for all columns of table.
Like if I have column "int" which have null then it will 0 and "string" will "".

Is it possible with a single SQL query?

I don't want to execute separate queries for update and set not null because I have many tables and have many columns.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There's no *magic shortcut* - you will need to use an `UPDATE` command for each table, and you need to list each column you want to update separately:

```
UPDATE dbo.YourTable
SET IntColumn = ISNULL(IntColumn, 0),
    VarCharColumn = ISNULL(VarCharColumn, "")
```

and so on....

Answer (score 0):

there is no real shortcut from sql server to do this, but u can use dirty way and u need be careful when using it.

```
declare @tableName varchar(200) = 'TABEL1'
declare @query1 varchar(max) = ''

select @query1 = @query1 + (case when @query1 = '' then '' else ', ' end) 
    + a.name +' = isnull('+a.name+','+  (case when a.system_type_id in (56) then '0' when a.system_type_id in (167) then '''''' else a.name  END) +')'
from sys.all_columns a
inner join sys.all_objects b
    on a.object_id = b.object_id
where b.name = @tableName

set @query1 = ' UPDATE '+ @tableName +' SET '+ @query1

execute(@query1)
```